# vim: insert successive numbers in a row

Tags: vim

Let's say I want to initialize this tuple:

```
t = (
    #(id, name)
     (1, 'aasd'),
     (2, 'bsfd'),
     (3, 'asf'),
         ...
     (21, 'aefae'),
)
```

I am sure I can do as follow with vim.

**1/ Type this:**

```
t = (
    #(id, name)
     (, 'aasd'),
     (, 'bsfd'),
     (, 'asf'),
         ...
     (, 'aefae'),
)
```

**2/ Visual select comma row, and type a tricky key sequence which would write successive number**

Does anyone know what is the tricky key sequence I should type?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of using VisIncr newer vims (starting with Version 8) support incrementing in visual mode. So I would go with:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> and mark the column with the commas
- <kbd>I</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd> to initialize each column to 1
- Visually block select the **second** to last row (using e.g. <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>)
- press <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> to have each row sequentially incremented.

Answer (score 4):

This can be solved with a *macro*

1. Position the cursor on the first number: `3Gf1`
2. Start recording: `qq`
3. Yank the number `lyT`, go one down `j`, paste `P`, increment `^A` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>A</kbd>), stop recording `q`.
4. Execute the macro for the remaining lines: `20@q`

All together: `3Gf1lyT(jP^Aq20@q`

---

To avoid the counting, and apply the increment until there are no more lines, you can also turn this into a *recursive macro*:

1. Position the cursor on the first number: `3Gf1`
2. Clear macro register `q` and start recording: `qqqqq`
3. Yank the number `lyT`, go one down `j`, paste `P`, increment `^A` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>A</kbd>), re-invoke macro `@q`. All together: `lyT(jP^A@q`

Answer (score 2):

Using the [VisIncr](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=670) plugin:

- press <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd> and mark the column with the commas (that is, where you want the numbers)
- <kbd>Shift-i</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> - this should insert a column of `1`s
- <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> - mark the column of `1`s
- `:I` - this should change the column of `1`s into numbers `1` ... `21`.